# What is the correct term for a "universal accessor"

Tags: oop

In the active record pattern and in the builder pattern one may encounter so called "fluid" methods with non-verb names such as

```
 public function carRadio(...);
 public function driver(...);

 The ellipsis (...) indicates zero or more arguments.
```

The purpose of the above is brevity. Sometimes exposing a public property is enough, but sometimes you want to do more stuff than simply assign an object.

e.g.

```
$kid = Kindergarden::find(33);
$kid->food($carrot);
assert($carrot == $kid->food());
```

Roughly, this means give some food to the child, but in the food method you may want to check for allergies or some such.

A bulilder-pattern example could look like:

```
$threeThousandWatts = Generator::create();
$threeThousandWatts->wires($w)->fuel($gas)->schedule($timeSlot);
```

...you get the idea.

The question is, what do you (*literature you have read*) call a mutator that is also a an accessor?

PS. This is not a for a public API. It's just a generic question.

Comment: I'd call that an horrible anti-pattern. Methods that are both getters and setters violates the CQS principle and just whished their programming language supported property getters and setters like in C# or JavaScript for instance. The kid example would be an horrible design: it should be `$kid.feed($carrot)` at least. Also, for builders these methods are generally just setters. There is no point in making these getters as well. Finally, getters and setters should be avoided most of the time, unless it's a CRUD design.

Comment: @plalx Thanks for the comment. I find gettersetters to be neat and practical in cases where the class is a parcel of sorts or a (semi) immutable message :) I don't think all principles must be observed everywhere at all times. Sometimes you just want to write something that works and if others understand what it is, it's all good!

Comment: There is no such thing like semi-immutability. There is mutable and immutable. The fact that only one member of a 100 members class is mutable still makes that class mutable and there is no practical use in seing it as semi-immutable. It still wouldn't be thread-safe and still couldn't be shared without second thoughs. I'm not saying individual getters and setters are always bad, I'm saying that having a method that is a both, a getter and a setter is. It makes both, the API and the implementation more complex. If you want getters and setters then be explicit.

Comment: That pattern really reminds me of those people who are proud of writing a complex algorithm in an incomprehensible one-liner or people that thinks that having a single `update` method taking 10 parameters to fulfill different use cases is better than having one dedicated method per use case.

Comment: If it was difficult to write then it should be difficult to read ;) hahaha